# How to load native album video using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm an undergraduate student and I'm witring an iPhone HumanSeg app. But now I have a problem, that I have a native video in album, and I need to load that video into my code and do some processing. My codes are below:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp4")
let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
let avAsset = AVAsset(url: videoURL as URL)
```

But when I run this code, Xcode just tells me that filePath is nil. I assert that 1.mp4 is in both Assets.xcaassets and iPhone album. Is there anyone who'd like to offer some help?

By the way, How can I get the images(in UIImage format) in the video at the fastest speed? For each image at given time, I really have to read it in no more than 5ms so I may output the preserved video at a good fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check target's build phases, whether the file is being copied to the bundle.Also the check the box to include the file. This code is correct for fetching that file.

Comment: Yeah, it's just SOOOOO nice of you. Thanks to your help I solved this problem.